# "Question promotion" ads for Information Security are still using old logo

Tags: bug, status-completed

"Question promotion" ads, generated on the fly form popular questions list, are still using old logo, with "IT Security" caption. Screenshot from today:

[image: "Question promotion" ad with old logo]

Comment: @TildalWave My bad, this is **NOT** community promotion ad. This is "question promotion"(?) ad, that are generated on the fly.

Comment: @TildalWave This one is from Math Stackexchange sidebar, but in past I have seen them on other SE network sites also.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We replaced the background image with an updated version:

[image]

It might take a few days for the change to propagate to new ads because caching.

Comment: Thanks Anna - I hadn't even spotted it.